# jinja: access nested dict without key errors

Tags: python, jinja2

I have a nested dict from a json api call and want to display values from deep within the dict

```
{{ context.city.houston.street }}
```

It could be that this value is not present in the dict. How can I avoid key errors in a deeply nested dict in Jinja?